# Woocommerce pull all products that are only 1 word different in Name?

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce I would like to show on my single products page an extra section that lists all products with a similar name.

The search criteria for the products in my database should be the following:
1. Product Name is 1 word different than the current single page product Name.
2. Is visible/published
3. In Stock

E.g. this is the exact display I would like to see:

```
Current Product is: This is Cool Shirt Blue S

Other options:
This is Cool Shirt Blue M
This is Cool Shirt Blue L
```

The reason I want to do this is because the manufacturer gave me over 50,000 product listings with no clear way to create variable items. It would take too much time to manually group the products together to generate variations. This way, I could quickly hack something that makes it similar to variation products, while keeping everything as simple product.

Comment: How will you know what word to put in what product? You can create a custom field on each single product. When you display those list of product then get that custom field value of each product and echo it out infront/back of the product title. Is it fine ?

Comment: No that doesn't work. I think its quite a simple question I am asking. I just want to search all products for the Names that are very similar to a certain target product name. It should be a query?

Comment: Oh you never mentioned about search part in your original post. So yeah you need to do a search query using that page product name.

Comment: But how do I limit it to make sure that only 1 word is different to the product name?